# Comparing two dataframes based on a condition

Tags: r, plyr

I have following two data frames. `df1` consists of an average size of a parameter for individual users. `df2` contains the average daily value for the same parameter for users.

I want to count the number of days for the events where `df2$size > df1$size` for *each* `user`.

```
df1 = read.table(text='user  size
AAL0706 29000
AAN0823 25000
AAV0450 30000', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)


df2 = read.table(text='Date    user    size
      2010-01-04 AAL0706 31054
      2010-01-06 AAL0706 20703
      2010-01-08 AAL0706 39968
      2010-01-04 AAN0823 17892
      2010-01-06 AAN0823 37839
      2010-01-08 AAN0823 19649
      2010-01-04 AAV0450 35432
      2010-01-06 AAV0450 37839', stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
```

Expected output is:

```
   user  count
AAL0706      2
AAN0823      1
AAV0450      2
```

I have tried to use the following command to calculate my results, but I realise something is wrong.

```
lapply(df1, function(y) { 
    ddply(df2$size, .(user), function(x) { 
        return(length(y$size(y$size > x$size))
    })
})
```

Could you please advice me of an efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `left_join` from `dplyr`, grouped by 'user' get the `sum` of logical index (`size.x > size.y`)

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df2, df1, by = "user") %>% 
            group_by(user) %>% 
            summarise(Count = sum(size.x > size.y))
#       user Count
#     <chr> <int>
#1 AAL0706     2
#2 AAN0823     1
#3 AAV0450     2
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1, .(count = sum(size > i.size)),on = "user", by = .EACHI]
#      user count
#1: AAL0706     2
#2: AAN0823     1
#3: AAV0450     2
```

Comment: Use of "dplyr" library was helpful for me in replacing most of the work I was doing with "aggregate" function. I was struggling with memory issues with "aggregate" function when processing large data sets. I believe "dplyr" package was a good alternative for my issue

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more straightforward solution using data.table would be to use the new `non-equi` joins feature available in the current development version of data.table, v1.9.7.

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df2)[df1, .N, on=.(user, size > size), by=.EACHI]
```

Each row of `df1` is matched against all rows of `df2` based on the condition provided to the `on` argument, i.e., match for exact value of `user` and look for all rows where `size` of `df2` is greater *within* that `user`.

Once the matching rows are obtained (for each row), the expression `.N` (= count of matching rows) is evaluated for each row, because `by = .EACHI` implies this. It instructs to execute the expression provided to the second argument `j` to run for *each* `i` (the first argument).

See installation instructions for devel version [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).